# How ember consider the host name and path?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

My Domain - 'http://bharath-1234:8080/folder/folder-id'
namespace - 'api/1'

I've a folder model which will contain the folder's response and I need to sort the model based on user's sorting. To that I do overwrite the `query` in folder's adapter. I do expect that my url will be like, `http://bharath-1234:8080/api/1/folder/folder-id/folder?sort[folder][last_modified]=desc` but it goes like `http://bharath-1234:8080/folder/api/1/folder/folder-id/folder?sort[folder][last_modified]=desc` this way. I need to cut down the `/folder` from my API call.

How can I do achieve that?
router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('folder', {path: 'folder/:fid'});
});

import ApplicationAdapter from './application';    // No I18N

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({

    query(store, type, query) {

        let url = this.get('namespace') + query.filter.value; // No I18N 

        return this.ajax(url, 'GET', null); // No I18N


    }

});
```

Comment: Try changing `namespace - '/api/1'` - note `/` in namespace

Comment: In my folder context I am calling an component in an add-on . In that component I am handling a sort logic in it and I am querying to sort.and I have defined namespace as api/1 in application.js adapter and I am making ajax call in folder.js adapter.

Comment: folder.js adapter file........import ApplicationAdapter from './application';    // No I18N
    export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
    query(store, type, query) {
    let url = this.get('namespace') + query.filter.value; // No I18N 
    return this.ajax(url, 'GET', null); // No I18N
    }
    });

Comment: when I print the output of the url in log it is going as expected like api/1/folder/folder-id/folder?sort[folder][last_modified]=desc.But while making call it is going like  http://bharath-1234:8080/folder/api/1/folder/folder-id/folder?sort[folder][last_modified]=desc.It is considering my host as http://bharath-1234:8080/folder...it seams but I for other ajax requests my host is considered as http://bharath-1234:8080 only...

Comment: just try `let url = '/'+this.get('namespace') + query.filter.value;`

Comment: Using ES6 string interpolation `${this.get('namespace')}${query.filter.value}`

Comment: @kumkanillam let url = '/'+this.get('namespace') + query.filter.value; works great!Thanks a lot man.